# Getting Kusto.Explorer to prompt for AAD authentication

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I've installed Kusto.Explorer 1.0.3.911 on Windows 10 1803 and tried to add a new connection to my cluster. I selected Client Security: AAD-Federated (the only option available besides None), but the tool gives the error `Unauthorized (): Authorization has been denied for this request` but doesn't prompt for AAD login.

"Inspect your AAD principal" does nothing, and doing a "Sign-out from AAD" doesn't make any difference. Is there some trick to getting it to prompt for the login? I'm sure I've had no trouble in the past on different computers.

Comment: Couple of questions (1) is the existing connection/s still work? (2) Is the new cluster in the same AAD tenant (directory) as the other clusters?

Comment: Is this a domain joined machine with all the OS updates? Can you access the Azure portal from a web browser?

Comment: I tried on a Windows 1803 virtual machine which had never run Kusto.Explorer before, and again on newly installed Windows 1909 Home virtual machine. Neither are domain joined. I'll try again on 1909 after installing all updates.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of time to edit the comment! I can access the cluster and make queries through Azure Portal -> <cluster> -> Query on the same VM. This is one our existing clusters.

I'll report back on if there's any difference once Windows is updated.

Comment: As a follow up, I installed all updates to Windows 1909, and this didn't make any difference. Is there any way to download and test older versions of Kusto.Explorer?

Comment: The error message you are seeing should have a field "ClientRequestId". Could you copy one from a recent failure here?

Comment: We're investigating a potential regression with the tool. As a workaround, can you please edit the connection, make sure that "Client Security: AAD-Federated" is selected in the Security drop-down, and verify it is there by examining the "Advanced Connection String". If it's not showing, add ";AAD Federated Security=True" to the end of the connection string (omit the quotes). Click OK and refresh the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have identified an issue with the Client Security drop down that can cause incorrect client security settings to be applied, resulting in authorisation failure.
We are releasing version 1.0.3.912 that will address the issue.

Erroneous connections will need to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks very much Vladik! I can confirm that editing the connection string in 1.0.3.911 worked, and version 1.0.3.913 no longer has the bug at all.